# Check if assets are installed in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to run a unit test that checks if the assets are properly installed.
I simply make a request to an existing file and check if there is no errors:

```php
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/bundles/mybundle/css/bg.css');
$this->assertFalse($client->getResponse()->isNotFound(), "Assets seem to not be installed");
```

Unfortunately, after checking with the Response instance, it always tries to reach some kind of controller with a route:

No route found for "GET /bundles/mybundle/css/bg.css"

Is there a way to make a pure request here without going through the routing system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use an actual HTTP client (the client implementation you are using for functional testing doesn't actually make HTTP requests) to make that request, but you seem to be approaching this the wrong way. Installing assets should be part of your post deployment scripts -- thus the test would always (or sometimes depending on the configuration of your development box, but the point is that it's a deployment/staging detail) fail anyway. Just do a simple test in your deployment process in any language you want to make sure that the assets installed correctly.

Simplified example

```
<?php
system('git clone myrepo');
echo 'Pulled codebase';
system('composer install'); // install dependencies
echo 'Dependencies installed';
system('php app/console assets:install web --symlink'); // install assets
echo 'Assets installed -- testing for presence';
if( !file_exists('blah.gif') ) { 
   echo 'assets not installed! error!';
}
```

Comment: I think it's a valid way to check if the file is in the correct directory. It seems the unit tests are to test internal functionality (not really making any http connection); which I was not aware.

I see that making an actual request to check if the file is there is probably out of the scope and I should go the way you are mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

The test client doesn't actually hit your web server, it simulates a request directly through your application.

Therefore it could never be used to check if an asset exists within your file structure. It could be used for dynamically loaded assets, but that's not the case here nor is it usually a case.

As @Lusitanian suggested, you can use standard file functions PHP has to offer to check if it exists.

If you need help locating the path of these assets, check out the `Kernel::locateResource()` method:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css');
```

This will throw an exception if the resource was not found.

Comment: Makes sense. Yeah I just noticed the unit tests are not making any HTTP requests.
The locateResource will find the resources where they are, but it will not check if it has been installed.

Thanks for your answer. I will revisit that test by following what @Lusitanian proposed.